# Simplify PHP Condition

Tags: php

I have a loop that creates hexagons 3 in a row, but there is a small bug in the code if 3 are not used per row. To get around this, I have been applying a negative position using conditional code, but it's obviously not going to work on going without adding conditions to each step.

Does anyone know of a way of simplifying the following for future proofing? The condition just checks in increments of 3.

```
if($i == 3) {
   echo ".hex-2 { left: -24.7%;}";
} else if($i == 6) {
   echo ".hex-5 { left: -24.7%;}";
} else if($i == 9) {
   echo ".hex-8 { left: -24.7%;}";
}
```

I'd like to do something for this array too, which counts in 2 then 1, then 2 and so on;

```
if(in_array($i, array(1,3,4,6,7,9,10,12,13,15,16,18,19,21,22,24,25,27,28,30,31))) { echo "</div><div class='hex-wrap'>"; };
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

This should do it, though it definitely can be beautified somehow:

```
    $numbers = [];
    $n = 1;
    $numbers[] = $n;
    while ($n < 29) // Or whichever is the allowed maximum number
    {
        $n += 2;
        $numbers[] = $n;
        $n += 1;
        $numbers[] = $n;
    }
```

And then:

`if (in_array($i, numbers)) { echo "</div><div class='hex-wrap'>"; };`